Airflow connection configuration with Google Cloud Service Account
I have an Airflow instance mounted on AWS. I need to configure a connection to extract files from GDrive. I've already created a JSON key file for the service account. The JSON looks like:
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/....iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}

Now, I'm trying to complete the Airflow connections adding some fields, but not sure what and where do I have to fill-in the info. From my understanding I have to paste the content of the JSON file into the Keyfile JSON field. Then I test the connection using the Airflow Connection Test button I get : Invalid key JSON.

Any help would be appreciated.

You should paste there the JSON itself (including the brackets).
Keyfile JSON
Contents of a service account key file (JSON format) on disk.
Check documentation:
